# fine-uploader unique but ascending ID in filename on submit and cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

this issue relates to Widen Fine-Uploader ( https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader )

i got this multipart upload form. no autoupload. i want to upload a couple of images and safe them under an unique name for each image.

eg. you pick 4 images. upload via fine-upload. i already got a gallery id. all images should be saved under a filename using the gallery-id and an unique ascending number. like this:

1234-1.jpg
1234-2.jpg
1234-3.jpg
1234-4.jpg

sounds easy, but there are two problems:

- the image-id needs to be ascending without skipping any one. That may happen, if you cancel (remove) a file before upload. so the image-id needs to be set up AFTER selecting all files OR it needs to fill up empty IDs on removing a file.
- the order of the images must be strictly adhered to the order you choose files on input. the first image you pick, becomes 1234-1.jpg, the second one 1234-2.jpg ... so i'm not able to set the ID at the imageHandler script after reload. It would grab the first complete image that must not be the first image in order, because i use several simultaneous connections on upload.

I tried something like that:

```
.on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {
    var picId = id+1;

    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {
        'currentGid': 1234,
        'picId':picId
    });
})
```

or

```
params: {
        fileNum: function() {
        return $(this).attr('id');
        }
}
```

or using a fileCount++ but nothing works like i need..

Comment: What, specifically, is wrong with your current approach(es)/attempts (above)?  What is not happening that should happen?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you need these IDs to be determined just before the upload has started.  What if a user cancels one of these uploads in-progress?  You could very well end up sending 1234-1 for the first file, the user cancels the 1234-2 while it is in-progress, while the 1234-3 file is also in progress.  I guess I don't understand why you have this strict consecutive numbering requirement.  Why not just pass the value of the file ID along with the gallery ID and be done with it?  Also, why is the order the files are selected so important?

Comment: i don't want to offer a cancel on progress. there is no need for options after submitting.
The pictures will be showen in picture-id order. It might be that some galleries are showing continuous shots (story telling). This is why we need the order.
we are working for years with this ID-structure. a lot of different scripts stops working if a number is missing. we dont want to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application sounds a bit brittle, and it is probably in your best interests to address that.

You'll simply need to maintain a map of your unique ids along with the ids maintained for each file by Fine Uploader.  In your "submitted" handler, add a key/value pair to the map.  In a "cancel" handler, adjust the items in the map appropriately.  In an "upload" handler, call the "setParams" API method.  Your parameters will by the gallery ID, the unique ID you've been tracking in your map for that specific file, and be sure to pass the id of the file as your last parameter to the "setParams" call.  This lets Fine Uploader know that this parameter is only for that specific file.

Please see the [callbacks documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/callbacks.html) for more info.

Here's a code example:

```
var fileIds = [];

$('#myFineuploaderContainer').fineUploader({
   //set your options here
})
   .on('submitted', function(event, id, name) {
      fileIds.push(id);
   })
   .on('cancel', function(event, id, name) {
      var fileIdPosition = $.inArray(id, fileIds);      
      fileIds.splice(fileIdPosition, 1);
   })
   .on('upload', function(event, id, name) {
      var params = {
         currentGid: 1234,
         picId: $.inArray(id, fileIds)
      };

      $(this).fineUploader('setParams', params, id);
   });
```

Comment: i don't get it. what do you mean with map?

Comment: An object with properties for each Fine Uploader file ID and values that equal your unique ID.

Comment: I'm not even sure, if I get you right. Sorry, I'm new to js. you mean, like an array which includes every file id? that could work and there is no need for a second id, if i use the value position to create my ASC id. but I don't know how to create such an array map or rather delete a value on cancel event. :-/

Comment: I updated my answer with some example code.  Hope this helps.

Comment: that is what I figured out by myself, too. but your solution is still better then mine. :) Thanks a lot for your support Ray!